# Plotting Step Functions - connecting the steps?

Tags: graphing-functions

How does one choose whether or not to draw vertical lines connecting the steps of a step function?

Let's take the cdf of some discrete random variable as an example.

My intuition tells me to graph it this way:

[image: connected]

... but many sources have the graphs drawn this way:

[image: not connected]

Is this a case of six of one, half a dozen of the other? Or is there some important difference?

Comment: You are doing it right. Whatever the books are graphing, it ain't a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your graph is correct.  The vertical segments you see in the second graph may be a result of a graphing program that is set in continuous mode so that it connects the dots even when they should not be connected, as in a step function or at a vertical asymptote.

A function $f$ associates a unique value $f(x)$ to each $x$ in its domain.  When we graph a function of $x$, we let $y = f(x)$, so there is a unique value of $y$ corresponding to each $x$-value.  Consequently, a vertical line can intersect the graph of a function at most once (the [*Vertical Line Test*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test)).  Thus, a graph that contains a vertical segment is not a function of $x$.